# How to run two methods asynchronously, get the results, use it in third method and return the result from third method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to achieve something like this:
To run two methods asynchronously, which return list with identical objects. Once both are executed, so I can pass down in the code both results in a third function.
I read a lot about CompletableFuture, but something doesn't work.
An example of what I want to achieve:

```
 B getResults() {
    List<A> a = new ArrayList<A>();
    List<A> b = new ArrayList<A>();
    List<A> results = new ArrayList<A>();

    // 1/ Call two methods asynchronously to get results for the first and for the second 
   a = getFirstResults();
   b = getSecondResulst();
   //        2 / Use results a and b to populate results
   results.addAll(a);
   results.addAll(b);        
   B finalResults = new B <>();        
   //       3 / Populate finalResults
   finalResults.setResults(results);

   return finalResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that used to `CompletableFuture` but, here is in a test how I approached a very similar scenario:

```
@Test
void completable() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> taskA = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return resultsFromA();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    });
    CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> taskB = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            return resultsFromB();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    });
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result = Stream.of(taskA, taskB).map(CompletableFuture::join).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    assertThat(result, is(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)));
}

private static List<Integer> resultsFromA() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    return Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}

private static List<Integer> resultsFromB() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    return Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
}
```

`resultsFromA` and `resultsFromB` should match your `getFirstResults` and `getSecondResulst`. I wrap them in a `CompletableFuture` and compose them as stream. Matchers and assertions came from `Hamcrest`.